# C++ Passing pointer in singleton-Program has stopped working?

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

So I tried to develop a class Scoreboard and a class Player and a class Player2(All singleton) and each play should possess a pointer to this Scoreboard.
When I run my program it stopped working and I believe it is because of the pointer because it occurs when I tried to access the Scoreboard that the Player point at.
So the basic idea is :

```
class Player
{
private :
    static Player *instance;
    Player(Scoreboard* sb2)
    {
        s=sb2;
    }
public:

    Scoreboard *s;

    static Player *ins(Scoreboard* sb)
    {
        if (NULL==instance)
        {
            instance=new Player(sb);
        }
        return instance;
    }

};
Player* Player::instance=NULL;
```

And in main function, the call would be :

```
Scoreboard* si= Scoreboard::startGame();
ply1=Player::ins(si);
```

Comment: `Player(Scoreboard sb2) {s=&sb2;}` - here you're taking the address of a copy of the scoreboard. Try passing a pointer to `Scoreboard`.

Comment: So in main() I have to write ply1=Player::ins(si); ?

Comment: `static Player *ins(Scoreboard sb)` --> `static Player *ins(Scoreboard *sb)` **and** `Player(Scoreboard sb2)` --> `Player(Scoreboard *sb2)` **and** `s=&sb2;` --> `s=sb2;` **and** `ply1=Player::ins(*si);` --> `ply1=Player::ins(si);` Google for "pass by reference", "pass by value", "pass by pointer" for C++.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did and still the programm stopped working

Comment: What exactly means stopped working? Please provide a complete, minimal but verifiable example, e.g. the error could come from the code you're not showing.

Comment: @sje397 see my edited code

Comment: @alexlop see my edited code

Comment: @danieljour Because I succeeded access the member in the scoreboard after I called Scoreboard::startGame()  . But after I passed the pointer to construct the player I can not access the member in the scoreboard through player. For example,if there's a line of code like play1->s->num, the program will collapse.

Comment: I think we need to see more code. How are you managing the scoreboard instance outside of the pointers in Player?

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
Player* Player::instance=NULL;
```

to

```
Player Player::*instance=NULL;
```

Comment: Really? Error shows up    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Comment: Answer needs an explanation of why this would solve the OP's problem. Without helping the OP to understand, a block of code just promotes cargo cult programming.